# Interpretting MSBuild output numbers

Tags: msbuild

What do these numbers (10:4, 37, 10:5) mean in the following MSBUILD output?

```
10:4>Done Building Project "C:\Foo.csproj" (default targets).
  37>Project "C:\Bar.csproj" (37) is building "C:\Foo.csproj" (10:5) on node 3.
10:5>Building with tools version "4.0".
```

Comment: This is such an important question... `mbsuild` output structure is not documented anywhere and it's a pain in the neck to figure out certain build failures.

Comment: For anyone getting here for MSBuild console/output log interpretation (especially structure and hierarchy), check out this project: https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building a solution, multiple projects are built, and you'll see each with a unique number (the '37' above).  Calling out to the MSBuild task from one project to another will give a similar result, it is similar to a 'recursion depth' indicator.  The 10:4> is typically related to which 'node' is being used in a multi-processor build, though I'm unfamiliar with the ':' syntax for this indicator and have only seen it with a single number.  Are you doing a build with /m, from a solution, or what other differences might be in play in your situation (e.g. TFS)?

Comment: I'm running msbuild against a Team Build project file (TFSBuild.proj) with the /m option on an 8 logical core machine.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: This is not an answer. The 10:5 syntax is not explained at all. I'm seeing these and I'm not using the /m option.